# how to call a python program from html

Tags: python, html, linux

I have a form in html with action = "pyth.py"

and pyth.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')
print('<html><head></head><body>My first page</body></html>')
```

so when i click submit in form it should run the pyth.py and should give me an html output. but it is not. please help me

Comment: This sounds like something that would need to be hosted on a local server instance that uses WSGI or CGI.

Comment: yes this is hosted in a  linux apache server with changes to apache2.conf to, but still not working

Comment: can you try this now, 52.91.241.71/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the python script in *cgi-bin* of your webserver. Your html form action should be `action="/cgi-bin/pyth.py"`. [Check out this tutorial](http://cgi.tutorial.codepoint.net).

Comment: @jamuna What output do you see when you submit the form? Some error? The python code printed as text?  Can you edit the question please adding more details, also can you post your html code?

Comment: the whole thing is printed again with out been executed. "#!/usr/bin/python
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')
print('<html><head></head><body>My first page</body></html>')"

Comment: @jamuna Is python installed on your webserver? Do you have permission to run cgi scripts?

Comment: yes , python is installed and changed these lines in config file 



`<Directory /var/www/>
 Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Indexes +MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
 AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>`

Comment: @jamuna in http://52.91.241.71/test/hello.html  action is _dataware.exe_. Can you fix it with the python file? Also don't leave your python script in websites's directory _www_, put it in **cgi-bin** and change form action to `action="/cgi-bin/pyth.py"`.

Comment: @jamuna link is now offline, anyway pyth.py is still not in _cgi-bin_ folder.